# Alternatives to covariant HashMap in Scala

Tags: scala, covariance

I need a map-like mutable data structure in Scala that is covariant in it's value type parameter. This is impossible to implement in Scala because mutable data structures are invariant in their type parameters. I understand the rationale for that decision, however, since that data structure will not be publicly exposed I need some "unsafe" variant of this data structure. How would you implement an alternative for this in Scala?

Comment: Why do you "need" it to be covariant if it is not going to be publicly exposed anyway? Just use the superclass as type parameter, and downcast as needed. Better yet, don't use mutable structures. Chances are you don't really "need" that either.

Comment: Would posting an example use help clarify? How is it supposed to be mutable at the same time as you're using its covariance?

Comment: @Dima you're right, that's the best solution. Thank you